# macOS electron build fails AppStore submission with "Exited with exit code: 173"

Tags: macos, electron, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I recently tried to submit a new macOS Electron app to AppStore but it was rejected with the following error:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance
>
> We noticed that with a valid receipt installed, your app quits on
> launch. The Console reports the app "Exited with exit code: 173" and
> the OS states the app "is damaged and can't be opened." This generally
> indicates that the app is not verifying its receipt correctly.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app and test it to ensure that it runs as expected.
> For more information on using receipt validations, you may want to
> review the Receipt Validation Programming Guide.
>
> If you are unable to reproduce this issue, ensure you are testing the
> exact version of the app that you submitted for review, and that
> you're doing so in a minimally privileged environment. See Technical
> Q&A QA1778: How to reproduce bugs reported against Mac App Store
> submissions.
>
> For additional information on crash reports, see Diagnosing Issues
> Using Crash Reports and Device Logs.
>
> Please see attached screenshot for details.

[image]

I'm not sure what receipt they are refering to. We do not use any IAP. I tried to submit 3 times but they reply all the time with same message.

The previous version of app was submited around 1 year ago.

Could anyone point me to what exactly they mean, cause I'm simply running out of ideas what is required from our side.

Comment: Could you find solution to it by any chance?